# Синонимизировать [ef-core] с [entity-framework-core]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать [ef-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core) с [entity-framework-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) и сделать основной более развёрнутую метку [entity-framework-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core).

Также добавить синоним [entity-framework-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-7). Это первоначальное название [entity-framework-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core)

Comment: [tag:entity-framework-7] туда же.

Comment: @Suvitruf Добавил в вопрос, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метки доблестно синонимизированы

Comment: И объединены (только что)